# how to make autologin in windows form application when it connects on online database remotely

Tags: c#, winforms

i am working on a windows form application in which i have to make an autologin window.i want that when user desktop connects with internet, Automatically login must be occur. My Desktop application is connected with online database.
Can Any body tell me that what is the procedure to do that.
Please help me i am stucked badly in that.

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [System.Net.NetworkInformation Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). In particular the [NetworkChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkchange.networkaddresschanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

Example:

```
NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged += (sender, networkAvailabilityEventArgs) =>
    {
        if (networkAvailabilityEventArgs.IsAvailable)
        {
            // Network is available
            // Try to open a database connection
        }
        else
        {
            // Network is not available
            // Stop trying to open a database connection, or clean up existing connections
        }
    };
```

**edit**

You can also call `NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()` to get the same information on-demand.

```
if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
{
    // Network is available
    // Try to log on
}
else
{
    // Network is not available
    // Do nothing
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! it worked for me. Now i also want to make automatic login for my application. How it will be possible?

Comment: @user3346501 I updated my answer with another trick that you can use. I can't help you beyond this point without looking at your code.

Answer (score 0):

Keep trying to connect to the database until you don't get any error (or at least you can reach the database).

You could also try telnet-ing the remote port, but you can't be sure there's one (if you use SQL Server it's possible you're using Named pipes or other protocols)

Comment: can u tell me more about named pipes and how can i use it in windows form application?? I started my windows form application on windows startup. But i want that until internet connection is not available ,it should not start. Can this be possible by using named pipes?

Comment: I started my windows form application on windows startup. But i want that until internet connection is not available ,it should not start.because first screen is of login and login should work automatically. Can this be possible by using named pipes?

Comment: it depends on the server configuration, can you give us some more information about the database server?